# Does logging on Google App Engine use up any quotas?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine and looking to reduce the number of read/write operations I make to the datastore. Does logging use up these or any other quotas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They don't count towards reads/writes but they count towards storage.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/billing#logs_counted_storage_quota